# Streamlit - Link a product image to its description

Tags: python, streamlit

I have created my own streamlit website for recommender system project. Input is a list of products and I use Cosine algorithm to recommend the similar products. The structure of website is random product(with product description, rating, price) and similar products (with name and image).

Is there a way to populate the recommended product's info(product descript, rating, price) in the same position with the original random product when clicking the image of recommended product?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do something on click of an image you can use the [st_clickable_images](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/custom-component-to-display-clickable-images/21604) library.

For example a counter of images click

```py
import streamlit as st
from st_clickable_images import clickable_images

# for global use
if not hasattr(st, 'counters'):
   st.counters = [0, 0]

clicked = clickable_images(
    [
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1565130838609-c3a86655db61?w=700",
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1565372195458-9de0b320ef04?w=700",
    ],
    titles=[f"Image #{str(i)}" for i in range(2)],
    div_style={"display": "flex", "justify-content": "center", "flex-wrap": "wrap"},
    img_style={"margin": "5px", "height": "200px"},
)

if clicked > -1:
   st.counters[clicked] += 1 
st.markdown(f"Image 0: {st.counters[0]}")
st.markdown(f"Image 1: {st.counters[1]}")
```

[image: Example of output]